# Javascript error.. Why does theLogin Form flash for a second?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a login form that pops up (onclick) but when I click into any page on the site it flashes for a second. It is generated using this plugin for wordpress http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/flexible-frontend-login/

http://oilfieldconference.com

To recreate simply load the site and click on the Calendar link in the navbar.. You will see the login form flash.. I dont see anything in the console..

[image]

Relevant Javascript (I think.. taken from console/resources):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
// $() will work as an alias for jQuery() inside of this function

// Add an empty container for overlay
$(document).ready( function($) {
    $('html').prepend('<div id="ffl-mask"></div><!-- added by Flexible Frontend Login Plugin. Needed for overlay. -->');
} );

$(document).ready(function() { 

     //select all the a tag with name equal to ffl-modal
     $('a[name=ffl-modal]').click(function(e) {
         //Cancel the link behavior
         e.preventDefault();
         //Get the A tag
         var id = $(this).attr('href');

         //Get the screen height and width
         var maskHeight = $(document).height();
         var maskWidth = $(window).width();

         //Set height and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
         $('#ffl-mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

         //transition effect    
         $('#ffl-mask').fadeIn(600);   
         $('#ffl-mask').fadeTo("fast",0.8); 

         //Get the window height and width
         var winH = $(window).height();
         var winW = $(window).width();

         //Set the popup window to center
         $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
         $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);

         //transition effect
         $(id).fadeIn(1000);

     });

     //if close button is clicked
     $('.ffl-window .ffl-close').click(function (e) {
         //Cancel the link behavior
         e.preventDefault();
         $('#ffl-mask, .ffl-window').hide();
     });    

     //if mask is clicked
     $('#ffl-mask').click(function () {
         $(this).hide();
         $('.ffl-window').hide();
     });        

});

// calculate mask when user resizes window
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).resize(function () {

         var box = $('#ffl-boxes .ffl-window');

         //Get the screen height and width
         var maskHeight = $(document).height();
         var maskWidth = $(window).width();

         //Set height and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
         $('#ffl-mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

         //Get the window height and width
         var winH = $(window).height();
         var winW = $(window).width();

         //Set the popup window to center
         box.css('top',  winH/2 - box.height()/2);
         box.css('left', winW/2 - box.width()/2);

    });
});


 $(document).ready(function() {

    // find all instances of flexible-frontend-login to append individual links
    $('a[name=ffl-popup]').each(function(){
        // get the tags from link
        var id = $(this).attr('href');
        // set linked div to hidden
        $(id).hide();                   
    });

    // select a tags with name equal to ffl-popup
    $('a[name=ffl-popup]').click(function(e) {
        // cancel link behavior
        e.preventDefault();
        // get the tags from link
        var id = $(this).attr('href');
        // Set visibility
        $(id).css('display', 'block');
    });

     //if close button is clicked
     $('.ffl-close-popup-link').click(function(e) {
         //Cancel the link behavior
         e.preventDefault();
         // get parent id
         var id = $(this).parents('div:eq(0)').attr('id');
         // and hide it
        $('#'+id).hide();
      });    

 });    

});
```

Comment: We need more information.  What the form is generated by.. your modules/extensions/what CMS you're using..  This is information we don't have access to.

Comment: Also, it doesn't flash for me.

Comment: Added that its wordpress and generated by http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/flexible-frontend-login/

Comment: We would also need the steps to reproduce the behavior..  I for one am unable to reproduce it.

Comment: Load homepage http://oilfieldconference.com/ ... 2.. click on the "Calendar" link in nav.. You should see the login box popup form flash for a split second that is supposed to only be triggered onclick. .. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I have a solution for you, but it involves editing the class files of the plugin you are using.  I looked at the JS.  It is not what is at issue.. what is at issue is the div in question is being generated on the page before the js then hides it.  To fix that, do the following.  Note that this is untested because I don't have wordpress and the plugin in question installed on my machine:

Go into `flexible-frontend-login\includes\classes\class.FrontendLogin.php` and find line 49, which should be this:

```
$html .= "<div id='ffl-popup-content-$unique' class='ffl-popup-content ffl-{$this->horizontal_position} ffl-{$this->vertical_position}'>";
```

Replace it, or edit it to be like this.  Either works really:

```
$html .= "<div id='ffl-popup-content-$unique' class='ffl-popup-content ffl-{$this->horizontal_position} ffl-{$this->vertical_position}' style='display: none;'>";
```

This edit causes the div in question to be hidden at generation, instead of hidden later in the js.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't post the javascript or anything, my best guess is you are making display none in the javascript and it doesn't run until after page load? Maybe go into your css and make it display none and onclick display:block?